# What is the best practice to separate Vuex modules?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

From an architectural point of view **what is the best to separate/structure the Vuex Store into modules?** I tend to create a module for each major routes when using Vue router.

When using this approach (diving modules by Views) I often occur the case that I have dependencies between the pages and Vuex modules.

The provided example of Vuex documentation is recommending a domain driven approach? 
    https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/structure.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually create my modules around my data rather than around the routes calling the data. The point of state management in Vuex is to allow access to data from multiple components and routes after all. So for example, if I'm querying an API for a user, I'll make a module related to that user object. Similarly, if you have a themed UI, I would create a module for switching themed elements. Or if you are using a toast notification to display success/error messages that might be a good candidate for a module.